# Extend CRUD functions

Tags: sails.js

I want to add some functionality to the built-in `create` function.

I have a model called user, and I know I can override the `create` function by declaring my own `create` function in the `UserController`:

```
module.exports = {

    create: function(req, res) {

        // Logic here for checking if everything is okay

        if (everything_okay) {
            // call super.create() ? <--
        }
        else{
            res.josn({ error: err });
        }
    },
};
```

I read through the docs, but couldn't find out how to implement the indicated `<--` line.

Comment: Based on your current question you'd probably be better off using the [`beforeCreate` lifecycle hook](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will have to ask another question about that.

Answer (score 0):

`// call super.create() ? <--` means this is the place where you call:

```
User.create(userObject, function (err, cretaedUserObj) {
  if(err) {
    //handle err
  } else {
    //user succesfully created.
  }
});
```

So basically, if all the parameters are OK i.e. `if(everything_okay)`, you create the User, else you handle that which is Not Ok.

Hope this helps.